# How would I continue to run code after importing a Tkinter file?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, import

So I'm trying to use a Tkinter window as an output log. My main program is a command line interface, so if the output from the "side programs" that run fills up the python console, it can ruin the user experience.

I have the Tkinter output log program in a seperate file, which I import into my main file. This is the gyst of the Tkinter file I created:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry('700x460')

console = Listbox(root, width=40000, height=30000, font=('Lucida Console', 14), relief=FLAT, bg='black',
                  fg='white',
                  borderwidth=0, highlightbackground='black', selectbackground='black',
                  selectforeground='white')
console.pack()


def log(what_to_log):
    now = datetime.now()
    console.insert('[' + now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ']: ' + what_to_log)

root.mainloop()
```

So I import it into my main program like so:

```
# this is the file with the Tkinter code
import Logs 

Logs.log('Test')
```

The issue is that the main program doesn't continue running after importing `Logs`, it just stops, and continues to run the `mainloop` in the `Logs` file.

So my question is,  how could I get both files to continue running, while also being able to update the Tkinter `listbox` via the `log` function??

Answer (score 0):

You should not execute `root.mainloop()` as it will block your console application.  Use `root.update()` at the end of `log()` to force tkinter to update the list box.  Also there is syntax error in `console.log(...)`.

Below is a modified `Logs.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry('700x460')

console = Listbox(root, font=('Lucida Console', 14), relief=FLAT, bg='black', fg='white',
                  borderwidth=0, highlightbackground='black', selectbackground='black',
                  selectforeground='white')
console.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

def log(what_to_log):
    now = datetime.now()
    console.insert('end', '['+now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+']: '+what_to_log)
    console.see('end') # make sure last log is visible
    root.update() # force tkinter to update
```